# Unexpected output regarding JavaScript lexical scope

Tags: javascript

This is my only JavaScript code.

```
(function (){
    var name = "Joby";
    console.log(name);
})();
console.log(name);
```

The console.log inside the function block is printing "Joby" as expected.

The outer console is printing  in console. I am expecting "Reference error" for outer console statement. Why is it like that?

I am using Google Chrome browser. Same output is shown in firefox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`name` is a `key/property` of `window` object, `name(global variable)` variable referred out of the `IIFE` refers to `name` in `window`

> [`Window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/name), *Gets/sets the name of the `window`*

```js
(function() {
  var name = "Joby";
  console.log(name);
})();
console.log(name);

console.log('---With some other variable name---');

(function() {
  var name1 = "Joby";
  console.log(name1);
})();
console.log(name1);//you can find `ReferenceError` here!
```

Comment: Thank you. That is a new information for me. I need to wait for 10 mins to accept this as an answer :)

Comment: @JobyJoseph, I'm glad it helped! _Happy Coding_